# EF4 - Easy way to load all related entities?

Tags: entity-framework, poco

In EF4 is there a relatively easy way to eagerly load all the related entities of an entity? I'm thinking an extension method would be perfect for this. I have a scenario where I'm using POCOs and one of the entities has multiple navigation properties of other entities and those in turn have their own navigation properties. Needless to say that is a lot of looping and loading to eagerly load everything. I want all properties to be loaded and ready when I call the extension method so I can turn LazyLoading off.

Something like:

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
   var widget = context.Widgets.FirstOrDefault();
   widget.RecursivelyLoadAllPropertiesForMe() // magical extension method I wished existed
}
```

Comment: Why "lot of looping"? You actually need only a lot of `Include` operators, possibly with dotted paths like `Include("Customer.Contacts")` etc. Having one extension method per entity for this is not the problem. But I am not sure: Are you looking for one single method which loads the navigation properties for all entity types without specifying explicitely all these `Include`s?

Comment: You have to define the includes before you fetch the widget however. Performance will be really bad if you attempt to load it all by just iterating and moving over all navigation properties.

Comment: @Slauma Exactly, I don't want to have to specify all the include manually.

Comment: You do realize with LazyLoading on it would do this all for you! (and efficiently since it only bothers getting the related items if you actually ask for them)?

Answer (score 2):

Eager loading is always explicit - no automation. You must define includes to all relations you want to load. If you don't do that you will almost always end with solution using new query for each relation.

Your extension method will have to use:

```
((EntityCollection<...>)entity.NavigationCollection).Load();
```

If you need to load sub relations you can also call:

```
((EntityCollection<...>)entity.NavigationCollection).CreateSourceQuery()
                                                    .Include(...)
                                                    .Execute();
```

But each call to `Load` or `Execute` will still create a new query to database and you must write a code which will do these calls. Also you must have proxied entities to be able to convert common `ICollection<...>` to `EntityCollection<...>` and you must load all simple navigation properties (not collections) with common eager loading.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the extension method I came up with:

```
public static void LoadAllProperties<T>(this T entity, ObjectContext context)
{
    Type type = entity.GetType();
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, entity);
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("ICollection"))
        {
            context.LoadProperty(entity, property.Name);
            var itemCollection = property.GetValue(entity, null) as IEnumerable;
            foreach (object item in itemCollection)
            {
                item.LoadAllProperties(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method first loads the normal entity property values by refreshing the entity from the context. It then loops through each property looking for navigation properties that are collections and will recursively load each item within the collection. This works rather well for what I needed and doesn't require you to use proxies or includes.

Usage:

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var widget = context.Widgets.FirstOrDefault();  
    widget.LoadAllProperties(context);
}
```

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I agree, I would only use this when you know that you are not loading a ton of objects.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is! Just go:

```
widget.Load()
```

Or if you went:

```
var widget = context.Widgets.FirstOrDefault().Include("SomeRelatedEntities").Include("OtherRelatedEntities");
```

you wouldnt need to!

Answer (score -1):

step 1
                    context.DataContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
                    context.DataContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

step 2
                   add virtual keyword to navigator property

```
  public class BankBranche 
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int BankId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
```

}